# Notation for set of (open) neighbourhoods of a point.

Tags: general-topology, notation

What is the most standard notation for the set of neighborhoods of a point $p$ in a topological space $X$?

I have seen $\mathcal{U}_X(p)$ and also $\mathcal{N}_X(p)$, but I never got the impression that those notations were standard. I couldn't find any answer to this in Google either.

And what about open neighborhoods?

*Clarification*: I am really looking for standard notations, so I hope that this question isn't interpreted as opinion-based.

Comment: In my topology classes long ago, we just used $N(a)$, the topology $\tau$ and the space $X$ usually being understood from context.

Comment: I guess it depends at least in part on the language. I'm partial towards $\mathscr{V}_X(p)$ (drop the $X$ if clear from context, or replace the $X$ with the name of a topology if several topologies on the same set are considered) - $\mathscr{V}$ comes from French voisinage. It's Bourbaki's notation, ergo standard.

Comment: Thank you Daniel! That was precisely what I was looking for. I don't know why I didn't come up with the idea to look for Bourbaki's notation myself. I declare myself also partial towards that notation from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* There is no standard notation for the set of neighborhoods of a point $p$ in a toplogical space. A preference might be given by the mother tongue of mathematicians, if they tend to

- $\mathcal{U}_X(p)$ which indicates the first letter of the german term *Umgebung* or to
- $\mathcal{N}_X(p)$ which indicates the first letter of the english term *neighborhood*.

> **Notational conventions from the great:** A small selection of definitions from authors whose books are often regarded as classics.
>
> - *[Elements of Mathematics; General Topology, Chapters 1-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540642412)* by N. Bourbaki: We find in section 2: Neighbourhoods
>
>   *Definition 4:* Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ any subset of $X$. A neighbourhood of $A$ is any subset of $X$ which contains an open set containing $A$. ... (and later:) Let us denote by $\mathcal{B}(x)$ the set of all neighbourhoods of $x$.
> - *[General Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3885380064)* by R. Engelking: We find in section 1.1: Topological spaces. Open and closed sets.  Bases. Closure and interior of a set.
>
>   If for some $x\in X$ and an open set $U\subset X$ we have $x\in U$, we say that $U$ is a *neighborhood* of $x$.

We observe the term **neighborhood** by itself is not standard, since some authors define *neighborhood* which is defined by others as *open neighborhood*. This makes it even harder to consider a specific notation for the set of neighborhoods of $x$ as standard notation.

> - *[General Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00462BLBA)* by J.L. Kelley. We find in chapter 1: Topologies and neighborhoods in the paragraph before Theorem 1:
>
>   A set $U$ in a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a **neighborhood** ($\mathcal{T}$-neighborhood) of a point $x$ iff $U$ contains an open set to which $x$ belongs. A neighborhood of a point need not be an open set, but every open set is a neighborhood of each of tis points. ... (and later:) The **neighborhood system** of a point is the family of all neighborhoods of the point.
>
>   Theorem 2: If $\mathcal{U}$ is the neighborhood system of a point, ...

**Conclusion:** First of all we should recall that the term **neighborhood** is not uniquely defined in the literature. We always have to check the definition used by the author. The different notation used by the authors above strongly indicate there is no standard notation.

Comment: I note in passing that $U(x)$ and $V(x)$ seem to be the preferred notations for "open sets containing $x$".

Comment: Thank's Markus, but I think Daniel's comment was really what I was looking for. It also seems to me, as you say, that there is no standard notation. But I find Daniel's suggestion to follow Bourbaki very nice. After all, it wouldn't be the first time that we take notations from them

Comment: @Pedro: I've added some information from the great which might be useful.

Comment: @DavidWheeler: I agree, at least with respect to the literature of the last three, four decades. I've added some information about the neighborhood systems which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments and the other answer, notation seems to vary widely. Instead, I will address the "other part" of your question-"...what about open neighborhoods?"

There tends to be a bit of waffling on this point-the reason being, one can define neighborhoods in terms of a topology, or define a topology based on a neighborhood system. This is much like defining equivalence relations in terms of a partition, or vice-versa.

Explicitly, we can define a neighborhood, if a topology has already been specified, to be a set containing an open set containing the point of which is it a neighborhood. As you can see, neighborhoods can be "very big", but the "larger" ones aren't of much interest to us, in general (topologies are "ranked", in terms of "niceness", in their ability to distinguish points at the "small" level-so, for example, the indiscrete toplogy is "very bad", i.e., not very useful).

On the other hand, if we define neighborhoods *first*, we can define a topology to consist of neighborhood sets which are neighborhoods of each of their elements. Either approach will lead us to the same place, eventually (convince yourself of this).

In analysis (rather than "pure topology") some preference is given for the neighborhood system approach, because the neighborhood system (at a point $p$) forms a filter, which lends itself well to generalizations of the concept of convergence in metric spaces. General topology tends to be (but not always) more concerned with "global" properties of the space, so the importance of particular points $p$ is not as great.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer David! I was already aware of all of this, though. My question had to do just with the notation. So this second part of my question was: how would you denote the set of open neighborhoods of a point? Say that we have a fixed notation for the set of neighborhoods, like the one you used $N(a)$. Is there a standard way to denote the subset of open neighborhoods? (or do you have suggestions if there isn't)

Comment: And anticipating possible answers, I am looking for something shorter and more abreviated than just $N(a) \cap \tau$